Problems With Developing An Undo And Redo System For A Text Field Using Jetpack Compose
I'm trying to develop an application that allows users to undo and redo changes made in a text field using jetpack compose.
There are two problems in particular.
Problem 1: The system put in place to delay whenever the text field changes are documented doesn't function as intended. A timer that activates whenever the user doesn't press keystrokes and resets whenever the user does press keystrokes, doesn't work.
Problem 2: Each character added to the text field is added to the history of the changes made to the text field as single character. It is supposed to document all of the characters added within a specific time frame and parse them into a single string.
Here is code from the application
        // Value For The Text Field
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        // List Of Changes Made To The Text Field
        var history = remember { mutableStateListOf(text) }

        // Index Of The List Of Changes Made To The Text Field
        var currentIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

        // Coroutine Scope
        var coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        // Boolean That Determines If Changes Are Being Tracked
        var isHistoryBeingTracked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        // App Layout
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            // Text Displaying The Current Index Of The History List
            Text(currentIndex.toString())

            // Lazy Column Displaying List Of Changes To The Text Field
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
            ){
                items(history) { item ->
                    Text(item)
                }}

            // Text Field
            TextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { newText ->
                    text = newText

                    // Action That Is Performed When A Change Is Made To The Text Field
                    coroutineScope.launch {

                        // Value is Reset To False When A Change Is Made To The Text Field
                        isHistoryBeingTracked.value = false
                        delay(2000)

                        // Value is Set To True When User Waits For 2 Seconds
                        isHistoryBeingTracked.value = true

                        // Condition That Performs An Action When User Waits For 2 Seconds
                        if (isHistoryBeingTracked.value) {

                            // New Text Is Add To History List
                            history.add(newText)

                            // Index Of History List Is Updated
                            history.size + 1
                            currentIndex = history.size
                     }}}
            )

            // Button That Clears The History List
            Button(onClick = {
                history.clear()
                currentIndex = 0
            }) {
                Text(text = "Clear")
            }

            // Buttons That Undoes Changes To TextField
            Button(onClick = {
                text = history[currentIndex - 1]
                currentIndex--
            }) {
                Text(text = "Undo")
            }

            // Buttons That Redoes Changes To TextField
            Button(onClick = {
                text = history[currentIndex + 1]
                currentIndex++
            }) {
                Text(text = "Redo")
            }
    }

The problems mentioned above result in the undo and redo buttons only removing and adding a single character at a time.
If someone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

The compose team has very recently added a TextField which natively supports Undo/Redo functionality.
It was formerly called BasicTextField2 and is now called BasicTextField(state).
This proandroiddev-article illustrates how you might use it.
val state: TextFieldState = rememberTextFieldState()

Button(
    onClick = { state.undoState.undo() },
    enabled = state.undoState.canUndo
) {
    Text("Undo")
}

BasicTextField2(
    state = state,
    // ...
)

Please note that the Basic- prefix indicates that the TextField doesn't come with any styling.
You'll therefore have to wait until there's official support by your ui-library or style it yourself

No, I can't find that anywhere on mine,  and unfortunately mine has styling. An undo and redo feature is one of the most common features in any application. Someone surely must know.

No, I can't find that anywhere on mine  Make sure you're using the latest compose (foundation) version

unfortunately mine has styling BasicTextField(state) accepts a TextFieldDecorator which you can use to add styling.
